# How to insert JSONObject inside MySQL using java?

Tags: java, mysql, json, jdbc

I'm trying to insert a JSONObject that contains a couple of JSONArrays in it inside a MySQL database that I have.

This is what I'm currently trying to do:

```
JSONObject fiveMin = new JSONObject();
JSONArray data = new JSONArray();
data.add(45);

fiveMin.put("data", data);

String query = "UPDATE frame_data.all_frame_data" 
            + "SET 5_min_data = " + fiveMin
            + " WHERE stock_id = 1";

stmt.executeUpdate(query);
```

However, it's giving me a null pointer exception.

Anyone know how to fix this? I've been stuck on this for days

Comment: for a start `+ " SET 5_min_data = " + fiveMin` - add a space

Comment: from your code and lack of stacktrace, it is impossible to say

Answer (score 0):

your Query is not correct you need a space after `frame_data.all_frame_data` because this now look like `frame_data.all_frame_dataSET 5_min_data`, change your Query to be like this :

```
String query = "UPDATE frame_data.all_frame_data SET 5_min_data = " + fiveMin
            + " WHERE stock_id = 1";
```

Second i don't think that there are a type `JSONObject` in MySql so i think you are using a varchar or a text to store your data, so `fiveMin` should convert to a String and not set like you do for example :

```
fiveMin.toString();
```

You query should look like this :

```
String query = "UPDATE frame_data.all_frame_data SET 5_min_data = '" + fiveMin.toString()
            + "' WHERE stock_id = 1";
```

I suggest to use PreparedStatement you can learn more here : [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Thank you.

Comment: The missing space was a typo. But anyway, I'm attempting to insert a JSONObject inside a JSON data type. converting it into a string also gave me a null pointer. Any idea/alternative on what I should do? I want an array like structure inside mysql that I can manipulate in Java